# change name of the pods via helm

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, helm

I am trying to run mongodb via helm. I want to run 1 primary replica and 2 secondary replicas.

I would like to setup the following naming for the 3 mongodb pods once they are created:
mongo-0
mongo-1
mongo-2
And lets say that mongo-0 would be primary.

When I run the following command

```
helm install --name mongo ~/charts/stable/mongodb --set replicaSet.enabled=true,fullnameOverride=mongo
```

The pods do not have require naming:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-arbiter-0           1/1     Running       0          15s
mongo-primary-0           0/1     Running       0          15s
mongo-secondary-0         0/1     Running       0          15s
```

Please any advice how can I change that ? I tried it also via changing values-production.yml but the same output.

Comment: Can you post output of `kubectl get rs`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the [mongoDB helm chart template](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb).

To be more specific you need to change following files.

### [charts/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-arbiter-rs.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-arbiter-rs.yaml)

edit lines:

> [`name: {{ template "mongodb.fullname" . }}-arbiter`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-arbiter-rs.yaml#L10)
>
> and
>
> [`- name: {{ template "mongodb.name" . }}-arbiter`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-arbiter-rs.yaml#L67)

And replace `arbiter` with the name of ReplicaSet you want.

### [charts/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-primary-rs.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-primary-rs.yaml)

edit lines:

> [`name: {{ template "mongodb.fullname" . }}-primary`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-primary-rs.yaml#L10)
>
> and
>
> [`- name: {{ template "mongodb.name" . }}-primary`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-primary-rs.yaml#L84)

And replace `primary` with the name of ReplicaSet you want.

### [charts/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-secondary-rs.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-secondary-rs.yaml)

edit lines:

> [`name: {{ template "mongodb.fullname" . }}-secondary`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-secondary-rs.yaml#L10)
>
> and
>
> [`- name: {{ template "mongodb.name" . }}-secondary`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/templates/statefulset-secondary-rs.yaml#L85)

And replace `secondary` with the name of ReplicaSet you want.

Comment: it is a good idea but not 100% effective. I am running the pods in statefulset so kubectl get rs returns no output. Here is kubectl get ss:

`kubectl get statefulsets
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
mongo-0   1         1         93s
mongo-1   1         1         93s
mongo-2   1         1         93s`

After changing the configs as Crou suggested I get pods like this:

`kubectl get pods
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-0-0   1/1     Running   0          39s
mongo-1-0   1/1     Running   0          39s
mongo-2-0   1/1     Running   0          39s`

Comment: Check this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274031/in-kubernetes-how-to-set-pods-names-when-using-replication-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

as my comment does not show in very readable form I ma posting my comment also here:

it is a good idea but not 100% effective. I am running the pods in statefulset so kubectl get rs returns no output. Here is kubectl get ss:

```
kubectl get statefulsets
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
mongo-0   1         1         93s
mongo-1   1         1         93s
mongo-2   1         1         93s
```

After changing the configs as Crou suggested I get pods like this:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-0-0   1/1     Running   0          39s
mongo-1-0   1/1     Running   0          39s
mongo-2-0   1/1     Running   0          39s
```

Now I would like to delete the -0 in the end so I get:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-0   1/1     Running   0          39s
mongo-1   1/1     Running   0          39s
mongo-2   1/1     Running   0          39s
```